# A function without dimensionality axiom

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $P:\mathbb{R}^{2n}_{++}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{++}$
, and let $x,y,x',y'\in\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$. Consider $n\geq 2$.

Let me define 4 axioms:

- Monotonicity:
  $P(x,y)\geq P(x,y')$, whenever, $y\geq y', y\neq y'$, and $P(x,y)\leq P(x',y)$, whenever, $x\geq x', x\neq x'$.
- Identity: $P(x,x)=1,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$.
- Linear Homogeinity: $P(x,\lambda y) = \lambda P(x,y)$.
- Dimensionality: $P(\lambda x,\lambda y)=P(x,y)$.

I want a function that has monotonicity, identity, linear homogeneity **but not dimensionality**.

We define: $x\geq x'$ as $x_{i}\geq x'_{i},\forall i\in{1,\dots,n}$.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think it is possible for n=1.
$P(x,y)=\frac{y}{x} P(x,x)=\frac{y}{x}$
$P(ax,ay)=\frac{ay}{ax}=\frac{y}{x}=P(x,y)$

Comment: What is your definition of $y/x$, since $y$ and $x$ are vectors.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks